# Cross-references anchors and links from a document in Word using the javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, office-js

How do I get cross-references anchors and links from a document in Word using the javascript API?

I am currently analyzing the document using the content returned from getHtml() however I have found that:

- in Word Desktop, the html includes the anchor but not the links to
  it.

[image: showing anchors in the html]

[image: showing no links in the html]

- in Word Online, the html does not include either.

Is there another way to get these?

Comment: The differences in what `getHtml()` returns are areal issue for us and I logged it as an issue here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/162

Comment: Have you tried with getOoxml? That should give you the REF fields and - IF your Range includes them, the bookmarks to which they refer. The bookmarks are the "anchors" for the hyperlinks; the REF fields generate the cross-references.

Comment: @CindyMeister - that sounds like a step forward however it makes it very difficult to retrieve the list item numbering... I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: I have seen that on beta there is a method to retrieve all bookmarks `getBookmarks(includeHidden: bool, includeAdjacent: bool)` (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_OpenSpec/reference/word/range.md#getbookmarksincludehidden-bool-includeadjacent-bool)... is there one to retrieve all the links to the bookmarks? `getHyperlinkRanges()` as far as i can tell, does not return bookmarks links...

Comment: More to the pont would be something to work with field codes, but that apparently has little priority. See https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33776575-add-support-to-read-field-codes-in-the-document-us and https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16473235-adding-field-codes-for-word-using-word-javascript